# Preprocess Node: Function that calls on all node types

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-nodes, drupal-preprocess

In `preprocess.node.inc` file, each node type calls its corresponding preprocess function. `mytheme_preprocess_node__article` for article, `mytheme_preprocess_node__bio` for bio, etc. Is there a function that runs on all these node types? I am trying to avoid using a function that needs to be called on each of these specific preprocess functions. Thanksin advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `hook_preprocess_node(&$variables)`. As in `MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)`. This works similar with nearly all elements.

- `hook_preprocess_page`
- `hook_preprocess_html`
- `hook_preprocess_field`
- etc.

They all are just variants from [`hook_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) where `HOOK` gets replaced with whatever element you want.

For certain elements you then can also attach the machine name of an instance to the function's name, to keep your code well structured when you have something that needs to be preprocessed only for certain types.

- `hook_preprocess_field__FIELD_NAME`
- `hook_preprocess_paragraph__PARAGRAPH_TYPE`
- etc.

For nodes you can also target the view mode, maybe this works for fields as well.

- `hook_preprocess_node__NODE_TYPE__VIEW_MODE`